# Is it possible to run callback after each promise completes and then another when all complete?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'd like to

1. create a series of promises (an API call via jQuery get/post)
2. run code after *each one* completes (such as a progress indicator)
3. run (different) code after they *all* complete

How's that done?

Something like this - but see question in the comment on the 5th line

```
var urls = []; // a bunch of URLs

Promise.all(
        urls.map(e => {
            return $.post(e);
            // do something here after post has succeded
            /// but still return a promise
        })
        ).then(d => {
           // do something when all succeed 
        }).catch(e => {
             console.log(e)
        })
```

I'm ok with using Bluebird

Comment: As someone with 1k+ rep you should know "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.". Take your time and provide an example of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: just add a .then to the promise in your loop, collecting an array of promises. then feed that array to Promise.all() and a .then on that will be your all done.

Comment: @kemikofa sometimes (as Mark mentioned) code will actually make the question harder, not easier to understand, and less generally applicable. IMHO, at least. Hence the avoidance of code, which I've now added, FWIW.

Comment: @mark-meyer - thanks. .then() returning a promise was the bit I was missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is pretty clear without a bunch of code. The important thing to understand is that `.then()` returns a promise. This means you can do work when an individual promise resolves by calling `then()` and save the return value from `then()`, which is also a promise in an array. You will pass that array to `Promise.all()` which will resolve when all the promises in the array have resolved:

```js
/* some async function */
let asyncFn = () => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), Math.floor(Math.random() * 1500)))

let promises = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let p = asyncFn()                             // then() returns a promise, save it in the array:
    .then((r) => {                              // do work for each promise
      console.log('done:', i, "returned: ", r)
      return r                                  // Promise.all() will received these values as an array
    })
  promises.push(p)                              // promises is array of promises
}
// Promise.all() runs when all promises in array have resolved
Promise.all(promises)
.then((arr) => console.log("Everything finished. Final values: ", arr))
```